# Snippet Database not working - PHP truncated HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this source code at the moment, but the issue I am having is that the site will not display code. It appears in the database correctly, but when being pulled from the database to the display page there seems to be an issue.

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($snippetinfo))
  {
  $dSnippetID = $row['snippetID'];
  $dSnippetDate = $row['dateAdded'];
  $dSnippetText = $row['snippetContents'];
  }
?>

<div class="container">
<div class="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo $dSnippetID; ?> <small><?php echo $dSnippetDate; ?></small> </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
     <pre class="prettyprint">

      <?php echo $dSnippetText; ?>

    </pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging before the section that is shown here; do any of the mysql statements generate an error, what does the complete query look like, do a `var_dump` of all relevant variables, etc.

Comment: If you want to output each row (and not only the last), put the output inside the loop.

Comment: Dear Santa, I was a good boy this year so make please next questions at SO with clear issue description, not just like "there seems to be an issue"

Comment: I am only really outputting one row at the moment, is it because I am pulling from the SQL database into the file, then saving it from the query to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you get only one result, but not all? if so change too [ ]

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($snippetinfo))
  {
  $dSnippetID[] = $row['snippetID'];
  $dSnippetDate[] = $row['dateAdded'];
  $dSnippetText[] = $row['snippetContents'];
  }


<?php echo $dSnippetID[0]; ?> <small><?php echo $dSnippetDate[0]; ?>
```

if you want get all results you maybe need a foreach loop

```
foreach($dSnippetID as $id){
echo $id;
}
```

if you dont get any rows; maybe `var_dump($row);`

and also post more informations :)

Comment: That's kind of silly to loop through the data twice. Forget the foreach, just move the while into the page a bit.

Comment: @josh your right, if he dont caches, than your way is better / faster...but i do it normal so, cause i cache results :)

Comment: @Josh That depends on how you work, personally I strongly disagree with you because I always separate my database stuff from my views. MVC, OOP and all these popular terms...

Comment: it outputs, just truncates the code, like if I was to save <html>hello</html> when I output it just displays Hello.

Comment: @jeroen: The software I write exercises very good design patterns. I just mean that for this particular example, it was silly to do double iteration. If the OP isn't aware of how to debug a query, I'd rather not try to confuse him with advanced topics.

Comment: @kneehighnerd can you post more code, to see, how you save the data and also check in your database if your input is **<html>hello</html>**

Comment: @kneehighnerd i think i found your problem, you see only in the browser hello, but if you look in the source code you would see <html>hello</html> cause the browser renders the HTML tags!